# view.animate().translationY() fill empty space

Tags: android, android-animation

Im animating my header view on scroll via the view animation classes as following:

```
view.animate()
.translationY(-view.getBottom())
.alpha(0)
.setDuration(HEADER_HIDE_ANIM_DURATION)
.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
```

Problem is that the view below the view im translating is not filling up translated views empty space:

[image]

[image]

My layout looks somethin like this:

```
<LinnearLayout>
   <include layout"toolbar" /> //included layout which is the view translated
   <FrameLayout  /> //fragment container
</LinnearLayout>
```

How do i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you try to fade away your toolbar?
Try to manipulate your FrameLayout manually.
Something like this:

```
        ObjectAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, -view.getBottom());

        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                toolbar.setTranslationY(-animation.getAnimatedValue)
                mFrameLayout.layout(mFrameLayout.getLeft(), animation.getFraction() * mToolbar.getHeight(), mFrameLayout.getRight(), mFrameLayout.getBottom());
            }
        });
        toolbar.startAnimation(animator);
```

Comment: same problem if i use relative layout. i dont want to change the height of it, just translate it

Comment: Ok, then try to change setY instead of the TranslationY. This should move the whole view and should have impact on the other layouts.

Comment: no difference either. the view moves, not the one below it

Comment: still does not update the layer below. i think layout() does not affect the view bounds only where it draws

Comment: I was confused. You need an Animator not an Animation and then you can add an UpdateListener. This should definitely work. I can give you some code later if you want to.

Comment: Does it work? I thunk you can do it with the updateanimator manually

Comment: I got it to work by animating margin top using Animaton classes. But this approach is wrong, the toolbar should be over the listview with an initial padding top for this effect instead!

Comment: And you decrease the padding? Also a nice version

Comment: any solution how to remove black space at bottom?